# Facing java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: web-services, rest, maven, jersey, restful-url

Trying to make a simple Restful service.

i used this tutorial to do it [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/jersey-hello-world-example/)

here is the link of jar using in this program

[image]

After follow each and every step ..... i face this error.

Please help ...

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>JAXRS-HelloWorld</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<repositories>
<repository>
<id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
<name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
<url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
<layout>default</layout>
</repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

java file

```
package com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/helloWorldREST")
public class HelloWorldREST {

@GET
@Path("/{parameter}")
public Response responseMsg( @PathParam("parameter") String parameter,
        @DefaultValue("Nothing to say") @QueryParam("value") String value) {

    String output = "Hello from: " + parameter + " : " + value;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

}

Error

```
Mar 28, 2015 6:51:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-helloworld-serlvet] in context with path [/JAXRS-HelloWorld] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status does not implement the requested interface javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.getStatus(ContainerResponse.java:599)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.commitWrite(ContainerResponse.java:157)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:134)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I've not used Jersey that much. If you don't mind building your server without Jersey, have a look at [this hello world example](https://github.com/testinfected/molecule/blob/master/src/test/java/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldExample.java) of [molecule](http://molecule.vtence.com)

Comment: Your `javax.ws.rs.jar` might be conflicting with the Jersey bundle as it uses bundled classes from the `jsr311` jar. There are conflicting classes. Try and remove that jar and see what happens